# Can't figure out how to clear a linked list in c++?

Tags: c++, list, linked-list, stack

I'm trying to figure out how to clear a stack (in the form of a linked list). Linked lists aren't my forte; I don't understand them at all. Here's my code, can anyone shed some light onto why it's not working? When I try to call the method through a switch in main, it seems too get stuck in an infinite loop.

```
void stack :: clearStack()
{
if (isEmpty()== true)
{
    cout << "\nThere are no elements in the stack. \n";
}

else 
{
    node *current = top;
    node *temp;
    while(current != NULL);
    {
        current = temp -> next;
        delete current;
        current = temp;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Looks like you're using `temp` without bothering to initialise.

Comment: I think you should read more and try to understand them better

Comment: `for(node *p=top,*t; p ; p=t ) t=p->next, delete p;`

Comment: That semicolon on the end of the while isn't going to help either...and most of the answers below just copied it so they won't work either.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with that code. The first is that you dereference an uninitialized pointer (`temp`) the other that you `delete` the `next` pointer before you loop (and thereby pulling the carpet out under your own feet, so to say).

It's as simple as

```
node* next;
for (node* current = top; current != nullptr; current = next)
{
    next = current->next;
    delete current;
}
```

Oh, and don't forget to clear `top` when you're done.

Comment: +1 and I think you can take advantage of having a `for` and declare `next` with the same scope. Just for fun ;-) (as in my comment to the question).

Comment: Since you are wiping out the list, you can actually move `top` along the list as you go and not have to clear it when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized `temp`. You need to set `temp` to the first node of the list. Inside the loop, cycle through the nodes and keep deleting them.

```
node *current = top;
node *temp = top; //    initialize temp to top
while(current != NULL);
{
    temp = temp -> next; // increase temp
    delete current;
    current = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think this is what you wanted to do:

```
node *current = top;
while(current != NULL);
{
    node *temp = current->next;
    delete current;
    current = temp;
}
top = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isEmpty()== true)
{
    cout << "\nThere are no elements in the stack. \n";
}
else 
{
    node *current = top;
    node *temp;
    while(current != NULL);
    {
        current = temp -> next;
        delete current;
        current = temp;
    }
}
```

That whole block can be replaced by:

```
while (top != nullptr)
{
    unique_ptr<node> p(top);
    top = top->next;
}
```

If the list is already empty, nothing is done.  If it is non-empty, `unique_ptr` takes control of the memory management of the current `top` (which will delete it between loop iterations), move the `top` to the `next`.  When `top` is `NULL`, everything is cleared and `top` is set to `NULL`.